# Getting Cherry-Pick conflicts

Tags: git, branch, conflict, cherry-pick

while doing cherry-pick of commits from branch development to master there is cherry-pick conflicts caused by missing commits in master (the order of commits matters).
So, I compare the log of commits in the two branches and I cherry-pick the missing ones.
this process is painful, especially when done on multiple commits.
Is there a git command or script to show the dependant commits that need to be cherry-picked before the one.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry

Comment: @phd i don't think you understand my concern

Comment: I'm sure I do. The command `git cherry` shows the list of missing commits.